# How to check if mouse is over the canvass in Processing 3?

Tags: java, processing

I'd like to write a function that returns `true` if the mouse is over the canvass, and `false` if not.

My solution would basically look like this:

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

Point globalMouse;

boolean mouseOverCanvass() {
    globalMouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); 

    boolean mouseInXRange = (canvass.X < globalMouse.X) && (globalMouse.X < canvass.X + width);
    boolean mouseInYRange = (canvass.Y < globalMouse.Y) && (globalMouse.Y < canvass.Y + height);

    if (mouseInXRange && mouseInYRange) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find the canvass position. I found [this solution](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/71292/#Comment_71292) to getting the location of the window, but this provides the coordinate including the top bar, whereas I'd like the location of the canvass within that window.

Comment: Based off of some searching I did, there used to be a function in Processing 2 called getFrame(), but this has been depreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the *mouseEntered()* and *mouseExited()* methods provided by PApplet, using a boolean variable to keep track of the current mouse-over-canvas state:

```
boolean mouse_over = false;

@Override
public void mouseEntered() {
    mouse_over = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseExited() {
    mouse_over = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find the solution for this, by the way?

Comment: @JamesKelleher These methods show up in my IDE when I type `mouse...`.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: @JamesKelleher I'm using eclipse.